# React js datetimepicker usage inside component

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-grid

I am a newbie to recatjs.I have a requirement to create a input field with datetimepicker using boostrap,as I am using boostrap datetimepicker cdn link and I don't know how to call inside component and get the values of datetimepicker in componentdidmount method.
Kindly provide me with a solution.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can help you with react date-picker it is so easy in install and usage

you can install it by this command

> npm i --save react-datepicker
>
> npm i --save moment

and this is my code i tried it and use it always, and with saving date value in handleChange function as the follow code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';

class About extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            startDate: moment()
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(date) {
        this.setState({
            startDate: date
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <DatePicker
                    selected={this.state.startDate}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    peekNextMonth
                    showMonthDropdown
                    showYearDropdown
                    dropdownMode="select"
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default About
```

for more information follow this link
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker